# I need to calculate the result for 1!/1 + 2!/2 + 3!/3 + n!/n in a Java program

Tags: java, math

I am stuck here:

System.out.println("Enter the number to be added to these factorial numbers:");
        System.out.println("1!/1 + 2!/2 + 3!/3 + "); //factorial ie. 5!/5 =  4 * 3 * 2 * 1 
        n = scan.nextInt();

```
     while (!exit)
    {

        if (n <= 2) 
        {
            sum = 1;
            exit = true;
        }
        sum = sum + i - 1;

        i = i - 1;
        if (i == 2)
        {
            exit = true;
        }
    }

     //m2 = 1 * 1 + (2 * 2) + (2 * 1) + (3 * 3) + (3 * 2) + (3 * 1) + (n * n -1);  
     //System.out.println(m2);
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: What is your problem, _exactly_? What does the program do that is an error?

Comment: I would like some input and desired output examples.

Comment: So you don't know how to calculate the factorials?

Comment: Yes im not sure where to go from here. 
I know that: 
1!/1 = 1, 
2!/2 = 2 because (2 * 1) / 2 = 1, and
3!/3 = 2 because (3 * 2 * 1) / 3 = 2 etc 

But how do i make sure the program calculates n!/n to output the right amount

Comment: Why `n!/n` instead of `(n-1)!`?

Comment: ie. if user input is 4. Then 4!/4 would be 6. Because (4 * 3 * 2 * 1) / 4 = 3 * 2 * 1 = 6

Comment: Why haven't you written a factorial function and tested it fully?

Answer (score 0):

Seems `n` is not changing. So you can move it out of the `while` loop. You asking for factorial, but I can't find a `*` here.. Maybe you can try this with for loop:

```
// say you got n = sth here
int sum = 0;
int factorial = 1;
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    // so factorial = i!
    factorial = factorial * i; 
    // add i!/i to sum, all the way to n!/n
    sum = sum + factorial / i; 
}
// sum is the result.
return n;
```

Comment: What needs to happen is. I need to calculate the factorial of the next int input "n" and add it to the rest of the equation (1!/1 + 2!/2 + 3!/3 + n!/n = ?).
I am not sure where and how to explain to the program this is how to calculate n!/n?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your main issue is to implement the factorial function. There are two basic ways to do this:

Iteratively, using a loop:

```
public static long factorialWhileLoop(int n) {
    long result = 1;
    while (n > 1) {
        result *= n--;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or recursively, which I prefer because it has no assignment:

```
public static long factorialRecurse(int n) {
    return n <= 1 ? 1 : n * factorialRecurse(n - 1);
}
```

As others have already mentioned, to calculate `n!/n` just use `(n-1)!`.

And if you want more performance, use a lookup table:

```
static final int [] FACTORIALS =
    {1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880,
     3628800, 39916800, 479001600, 6227020800L, 87178291200L,
     1307674368000L, 20922789888000, 355687428096000,
     6402373705728000, 121645100408832000, 2432902008176640000,
 };

int factorial(int n) {
    if (n < 0 || n >= FACTORIALS.length ) throw new Exception();
    return FACTORIALS[n];
}
```

There are not too many factorials that can be represented by a 64 bit integer.

However, if you need larger factorials, there are other specialized methods.

Comment: Neither the iterator nor the recursive implementations offered here are a good idea.  Both are as inefficient as possible for large n.  A better solution would use the gamma function and memoization.  Why keep recalculating expensive factorials?

Comment: @duffymo: Right, but seriously, the OP is obviously a beginner and has trouble implementing *any* factorial function. Do you really think it makes sense to suggest the gamma function or memoization here? But ok, I'll add the lookup table approach to my answer.

Comment: I agree that there are a lot of experienced programmers who don't know what gamma function is; it's well beyond somebody who didn't even think to write a factorial function.  This is a comment that is intended for all the people who come after thinking that the naive factorial implementations are the only way to go.